# Forecaster predict - No 'freq' argument was found

Tags: python, frequency, forecasting

I'm tring to run **forecaster.predict** but keeps giving a **'no freq' error:**

**The `freq` attribute of the time index is required, but found: None. Please specify the `freq` argument when setting the time index.**

I've split my dataset in training and test. My dataset is constant with daily values, and even if I use **asfreq('D')** to set the fh index to daily, it does not work. I'm setting the fh using the train index.

Can anybody help me, please? Thanks!

Code: https://github.com/dhgrassi/Grupo-de-Estudos-DS/blob/main/TCC_Teste_com_Dados_Reais.ipynb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code here instead of giving a link. This is because code on other sites can change over time. See this [FAQ for more detail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/17493431)